# How to create new snapshot in SSRS report by SQL Query for particular report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

It is easy to create snapshot for report on report server by click on new snapshot button through User interface, but i need to create new snapshot by using only SQL Query. It means what will be the SQL query by which i can create new snapshot for particular report on report server without using User interface? I

Comment: It is very urgent. Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is doable. You are trying to manage reporting server using SQL. SQL Server is meant to manage data not applications.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting the ReportServer database directly is discouraged.  The preferred method for generating an SSRS report snapshot is to invoke the [CreateReportHistorySnapshot](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/4/20/refreshing-an-ssrs-snapshot-using-t-sql.html) API method with C#.  However, if you must use SQL then have a look at the `AddEvent` ReportServer stored procedure.

```
exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='ReportExecutionUpdateSchedule', @EventData='<InsertReportIDHere>'
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/4/20/refreshing-an-ssrs-snapshot-using-t-sql.html) and [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/469781/Updating-a-snapshot-on-a-daily-bases-from-a-SQL-Server-job).  Below is a sample SQL script which can generate a new Snapshot for a given report on a daily basis.

```
declare @Path varchar(425)
set @Path = '/SSRS Testing and Training/Test_snapshot' -- the name of my linked report which renders from a snapshot

declare @EventData uniqueidentifier
select @EventData = (select ItemID from Catalog where Path = @Path) 

-- make a new snapshot in History table
exec ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent 'ReportHistorySchedule', @EventData 

-- !!!! wait until Reporting Services figures out that it has an event to process (it actually takes 5sec)
waitfor delay '00:00:10' 

-- take a snapshot ID from a newly created row in History table
declare @SnapshotDataID uniqueidentifier
select @SnapshotDataID = (select SnapshotDataID from history WHERE ReportID = @EventData)

-- set a date for a new Snapshot in Catalog table
-- use getdate() instead (select SnapshotDate from history WHERE ReportID = @EventData) because otherwise you'll get a UTC date for "last run date" in Report Manager which can confuse your users 
declare @SnapshotDate datetime
select @SnapshotDate = getdate() 

-- run a RS stored procedure which updates SnapshotDataID in Catalog table and some other necessary things
exec UpdateSnapshot @Path,@SnapshotDataID,@SnapshotDate
```